# Pass Multiple E-Mails in QV Exception Notification UPS API in PHP

Tags: xml, api, magento2, magento-2.3, ups

I want to send notifications to multiple emails but I am confused about how to pass the same in UPS API.

```
<ship:Notification>
                    <ship:NotificationCode>7</ship:NotificationCode>
                        <ship:EMail>
                            <ship:EMailAddress>'.$internalEmail.'</ship:EMailAddress>
                            <ship:FromEMailAddress></ship:FromEMailAddress>
                        </ship:EMail>
                    </ship:Notification>
```

$internalEmail contain comma-separated e-mails which is throwing error like The format of the first Email Address entered for Quantum View Notification - Exception Notification is invalid.

Any idea how to pass ? please guide

Rashi

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your CSV email apart in a list and then add a Notification element for each email address.